# Compare durations of different sign with lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

I am working with a dataset with dates:

```
a <- structure(list(ID1 = c(1, 2, 3), ID2 = c(4,
5, 6), dob.x = structure(c(-9954, -8960, -1219), class = "Date"),
    dob.y = structure(c(-1057, -1157, -9752), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA,                                                                            
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
  ID1 ID2      dob.x      dob.y
1   1   4 1942-10-01 1967-02-09
2   2   5 1945-06-21 1966-11-01
3   3   6 1966-08-31 1943-04-21
```

I need to get the difference between those two dates, and then use a `filter()` function to compare it with a fixed number of years, e.g.

```
a %>%
filter(diff > 21)
```

I tried to use lubridate for this task, but if I compute the difference between dates I cannot compare them, as they have different signs:

```
> a %>% mutate(diff = as.duration(interval(dob.x, dob.y)))                                                                                                   
  ID1 ID2      dob.x      dob.y                        diff
1   1   4 1942-10-01 1967-02-09   768700800s (~24.36 years)
2   2   5 1945-06-21 1966-11-01   674179200s (~21.36 years)
3   3   6 1966-08-31 1943-04-21 -737251200s (~-23.36 years)

> a %>% mutate(diff = as.duration(interval(dob.x, dob.y))) %>% filter(diff > years(22))
  ID1 ID2      dob.x      dob.y                      diff
1   1   4 1942-10-01 1967-02-09 768700800s (~24.36 years)
```

How do I keep pairs of dates with intervals over e.g. 22 years when I have negative values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`abs()` works on durations, as they're stored as elements of a vector with a sign (in seconds):

```
> a %>% mutate(diff = abs(as.duration(interval(dob.x, dob.y)))) %>% filter(diff > years(22))
  ID1 ID2      dob.x      dob.y                      diff
1   1   4 1942-10-01 1967-02-09 768700800s (~24.36 years)
2   3   6 1966-08-31 1943-04-21 737251200s (~23.36 years)
```

Comment: Posted my own solution as I spent way too much time on this trivial problem